# how to run Visual Studio 'Command window' commands in c# code.

Tags: c#-4.0

when i try to run the command 'Help.F1Help' from 'Command Window' (Visual Studio -> view-> other windows-> command Window) i can able to see the help file opening.

but when i try in c# with the below code nothing working. Any help would be appreciated

Code:-

System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            //startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            startInfo.Verb = "runas";
            startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            //startInfo.Arguments = "/C Help.LaunchinHelpViewer";
            startInfo.Arguments = "/C Help.F1Help";
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();

Comment: what kind of help you're trying to display "Help From Web page", or "CHM help" or other.

Comment: either one of them. if i set (launch in web browser or launch in help viewer) in the help->set help preferences any one of these are checked it should launch.

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(<path>);

Comment: It Will Work fine for url

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. sorry my requirement is no hard coded value if we physically hit F1 what ever triggers file from the command Help.F1Help that should trigger.

Comment: if i hit Help.F1Help in the command window it opens default help file that is configured in VS. so all i am looking for is to run this command from C#

Comment: you're developing console application or windows application.?

Comment: Extension package

Comment: hope someones have the solution. please don't forget to post if you got any solution.

Comment: I got it DTE dte = (DTE)ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(DTE)); ;
   // Get a reference to the Command window.  
   Window win =
    dte.Windows.Item(EnvDTE.Constants.vsWindowKindCommandWindow);
   CommandWindow CW = (CommandWindow)win.Object;

   // Input a command into the Command window and execute it.  
   
   CW.SendInput("Help.F1Help", true);

Comment: Any other alternative apart from above solution?